# How fast is the object’s shadow moving on the ground one second later?

Tags: calculus

A light shines from the top of a pole 20 m high. An object is dropped from the same height from a point 10 m away, so that its height at time t seconds is h(t) = 20 − 9.8t2/2.
How fast is the object’s shadow moving on the ground one second later?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x(t)$ be the distance between the spot $D$ on the ground below the object to its shadow.
now we got two similar triangles: $ABC$~$ADE$ where $A$ it's the shadow, $E$ it's the object, $C$ it's the top of the pole, $B$ it's the pole's bottom.
Must exist: $$20/(10+x(t)) = h(t)/x(t)$$
All you have to do is isolate $x(t)$, derive to get the shadow's speed, and assign $t=1$.